# Default layout for ember-cli, instead of "UnrecognizedURLError

Tags: ember-cli

I have something like this:

```
{{topbar-nav}}
{{outlet}}
```

I have a lot of pages, where I want to render just the top-bar, and nothing else. Normally, I have to create a lot of routes, that would basically do nothing (rendering emptiness), and I don't want to pollute router like this. Is it possible to somehow handle this situation? For example a default route like:

```
this.default_route("default");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found it myself.

```
this.route('default_page', { path: '/*wildcard' });
```

Important part is

```
{ path: '/*wildcard' }
```